# How can you get the merge field to take a url field from an object and set it to show up as a picture image in lightning email template?

Tags: email, fields, images, merge, template

I am trying to have Salesforce LEX Email Template populate a specific image from a field that's from a Account object and (fyi) the field data type is URL. My idea was simple, put the url into the html code and viola! But Salesforce doesn't like it, and doesnt want to enter the merge field into the html code for template builder. To visualize for example, say a doctor has a url that has his own picture and he wants to send a email to his patient, and he wants his picture to show up on the top right; this example will go the same for a woman doctor with a different patient. My question: is there a way to place an image from Account_field_url_data_type into the email template using merge field? Or what other solution is out there?

Answer (score 0):

A merge field is a placeholder used in an email, a letterhead, a mail merge template, a custom link, or a formula to incorporate values from a record. When you send the email, the placeholder is replaced with the data from the record or records of the people you’re emailing.

When creating custom HTML or Visualforce templates, use an img tag to reference the image. We recommend uploading the images to the Documents tab and referencing the copy of the image on the Salesforce server.

1. Add an image to the Documents tab.
2. On the Documents home page, open the image by clicking its name.
3. Right-click the image and get its reusable URL address. When you use
   the URL, you reference the copy of the image on the Salesforce
   server.
4. Open your custom HTML or Visualforce template.
5. Place the HTML tag , using the image’s URL address, where you
   want to insert the image in the email template.

Refer the help [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.email_template_images.htm&type=5)